# How to query the time duration of the same value within a given time range in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there any function in Apache IoTDB to query the duration when the status is a certain value within a given time range? For example, there are four kinds of different value in time series (like 1,2,3,4), and I want to query the time duration when the value is 3 in a given time range. I checked the user guide and only found functions like `ZERO_DURATION` and `NON_ZERO_DURATION` can return the duration of the value interval, but these only support 0 and not 0 values. Anyone know what other ways for me to achieve this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `group by variation` query command in Apache IoTDB to do that. For example, the statement can be `select time_duration(s1) from root.db.d1 group by variation(s1,0) having time_duration(s1) > 0`.